# Trouble scanning for collisions in javaFX

Tags: javafx

In my game, I need a class that scans for intersections between all nodes in its list, then calls an abstract method. For example, If a program had 100 balls, the class would detect any collisions between any two balls. The problem is, The class calls the method, even though nothing collided. Then, it doesn't detect collisions at all. Here is my code so far:

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

/**
 *
 * @author Jaca
 */
public abstract class massCollision {
    private final ObservableList<ImageView> oli;
    private final Thread t;

    public massCollision() {
        oli = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        t = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                while(true){
                    for (ImageView a : oli) {
                        for(ImageView b : oli){
                            if(!a.equals(b)){  //makes sure thread doesn't check an object to itself
                                System.out.println("scanning");
                                if(a.intersects(b.getBoundsInParent())){  //checks for intersections
                                    collision(a, b);  //calls the abstract method collision
                                    System.out.println("COLLISION!!!");
                                }
                            }else{
                                System.out.println("matched");  //lets user know when a duplicate is rejected
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Thread.yield();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public void add(ImageView n){
        oli.add(n);
    }

    public void remove(ImageView n){
        oli.remove(n);
    }

    public void start(){
        t.start();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void stop(){
        t.stop();
    }

    public abstract void collision(ImageView firstOffense, ImageView secondOffense);

}
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try: `a.getViewport().intersects(b.getViewport())`

Comment: Yeah, but what about the false detections?

Comment: @DarkDarker Also, when I use getViewprot(), I get a nullpointerexception.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the collison on an ohter way.
Maybe the intersects methode does't work right.

In my game I builded a Class like this:

```
    public static void detectCollectableObjects(SimpleEntity entity, Game game) {
    double x = entity.getLayoutX() - (entity.getWidth() / 2);
    double y = entity.getLayoutY() - (entity.getHeight() / 2);

    for (WeaponSpawn spawn : game.getWeaponSpawns()) {
        if (spawn.isWeaponShowing()
                && (spawn.getLayoutX() <= x && spawn.getLayoutX()
                        + spawn.getWidth() >= x)
                && (spawn.getLayoutY() <= y && spawn.getLayoutY()
                        + spawn.getHeight() >= y)) {
            entity.pickUpWeapon(spawn.getWeapon().clone());
            spawn.weaponIsPickedUp();
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Its not the best but it worked for me

Comment: I figured out why the collisions aren't working, but I think there's something wrong with the way I'm rejecting duplicates (That way, it doesn't detect a collision with self).